# Run python script with reduced permissions

Tags: python, unix, sandbox

I have to run some student-made code that they made as homework, I'm running this on my own computer (Mac OS), and I'm not entirely certain they won't accidentally "`rm -rf /`" my machine. Is there an *easy* way to run their python scripts with reduced permissions, so that e.g. they can access only a certain directory? Is PyPy the way to go?

Comment: "accidentally" is a bit optimistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [chroot environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). In this setup, the script can't access any files outside the chroot jail.

Comment: Would I then have to copy Python into the newly made 'jail' ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user account "student". Run your students' scripts as "student". Worst case, the script will destroy this special user account. If this happens, just delete user "student" and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, a simple way would be to run student code inside a docker container. You just mount the volume with the code and use an image with python.

e.g. assuming `/tmp/student_code` contains student submissions:

```
docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/student_code,target=/student_code python /bin/bash
```

you are dropped into a new bash session and can run `python /student_code/script1.py`